# Select how many rows up to a date

Tags: mysql, sql

having a list of people like:

```
name      date_of_birth
john      1987-09-08
maria     1987-09-08
samuel    1987-09-09
claire    1987-09-10
jane      1987-09-10
rose      1987-09-12
...
```

How can I get a result view using SQL of how many people are born up to that date, like the output for that table should be:

```
date        count
1987-09-08  2
1987-09-09  3
1987-09-10  5
1987-09-11  5
1987-09-12  6
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: OP also seems to have continuum dates in the result which are not in the table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another way, in addition to Gordon's answer.  It uses joins:

```
SELECT
    t1.date_of_birth,
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date_of_birth FROM yourTable) t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.date_of_birth >= t2.date_of_birth
GROUP BY
    t1.date_of_birth;
```

Note: I left out a step.  Apparently you also want to report missing dates.  If so, then you may replace what I aliased as `t1` with a calendar table.  For the sake of demonstration, you can inline all the dates:

```
SELECT
    t1.date_of_birth,
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
(
    SELECT '1987-09-08' AS date_of_birth UNION ALL
    SELECT '1987-09-09' UNION ALL
    SELECT '1987-09-10' UNION ALL
    SELECT '1987-09-11' UNION ALL
    SELECT '1987-09-12'
) t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.date_of_birth >= t2.date_of_birth
GROUP BY
    t1.date_of_birth;
```

[image]

### Demo

In practice, your calendar table would be a bona fide table which just contains all the dates you want to appear in your result set.

Answer (score 4):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select dob.date_of_birth,
       (select count(*) from t where t.date_of_birth <= dob.date_of_birth) as running_count
from (select distinct date_of_birth from t) dob;
```

This is not particularly efficient.  If your data has any size, variables are better (or window functions if you are using MySQL 8.0):

```
select date_of_birth,
       (@x := @x + cnt) as running_count
from (select date_of_birth, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by date_of_birth
      order by date_of_birth
     ) dob cross join
     (select @x := 0) params;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `subquery` with *correlation* approach :

```
select date_of_birth, (select count(*)
                       from table
                       where date_of_birth <= t.date_of_birth
                       ) as count
from table t
group by date_of_birth;
```